# How's requestretry sends request with json body?

Tags: node.js, request

When request sends a json body, it's like this

```
const request = require('request')

request.post('https://flaviocopes.com/todos', {
  json: {
    todo: 'Buy the milk'
  }
}, (error, res, body) => {
  console.log(body)
})
```

When i want to use requestretry, it has the same field json, but set to true or false, so how can i retry on send request with json body ?

```
var request = require('requestretry');

request({
  url: 'https://api.domain.com/v1/a/b',
  json: true,

  // The below parameters are specific to request-retry
  maxAttempts: 5,   // (default) try 5 times
  retryDelay: 5000,  // (default) wait for 5s before trying again
  retryStrategy: request.RetryStrategies.HTTPOrNetworkError // (default) retry on 5xx or network errors
}, function(err, response, body){
  // this callback will only be called when the request succeeded or after maxAttempts or on error
  if (response) {
    console.log('The number of request attempts: ' + response.attempts);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation, *Request-retry is a drop-in replacement for request but adds two new options maxAttempts and retryDelay.*.  You should be able to pass the JSON in `json: { ... }` like you would with `request`.